# Avraham bar Chiya's "Hegyon ha Nefesh" in Artscroll's "The Rishonim"

Tags: artscroll

Does Artscroll's "The Rishonim" mention the work "Hegyon ha Nefesh" in its entry on Avraham bar Chiya aka "Savasorda"?  And if so, does it say anything about it, and if so, what?

Comment: I suggest you buy the book instead of consistently making accounts to ask about entries within it

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant portion of their article on him:

[image: Artscroll's description of the sefer]